# Valgrind reports "Invalid free() / delete / delete[]"

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

I'm not sure what could be causing this.

```
==18270== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==18270==    at 0x400576A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:342)
==18270==    by 0x80537F7: LCD::LCDControl::~LCDControl() (LCDControl.cpp:23)
==18270==    by 0x806C055: main (Main.cpp:22)
==18270==  Address 0x59e92c4 is 388 bytes inside a block of size 712 alloc'd
==18270==    at 0x40068AD: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==18270==    by 0x8078033: LCD::DrvCrystalfontz::Get(std::string, LCD::LCDControl*, Json::Value*, std::string) (DrvCrystalfontz.cpp:652)
==18270==    by 0x8053F50: LCD::LCDControl::ConfigSetup() (LCDControl.cpp:71)
==18270==    by 0x80539F7: LCD::LCDControl::Start(int, char**) (LCDControl.cpp:31)
==18270==    by 0x806C025: main (Main.cpp:21)
```

Here's LCDControl's destructor where delete is called.

```
LCDControl::~LCDControl() {
    Shutdown();
    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = display_keys_.begin();
        it != display_keys_.end(); it++) {
        Error("Deleting %s %p", (*it).c_str(), devices_text_[*it]);
        if(devices_text_.find(*it) != devices_text_.end() && devices_text_[*it])
            delete devices_text_[*it]; // line 23
    }
    //delete app_;
}
```

Here's Crystalfontz::Get()

```
switch(m->GetProtocol()) {
    case 1:
        return new Protocol1(name, m, v, config);
        break;
    case 2:
        return new Protocol2(name, m, v, config); // line 652
        break;
    case 3:
        return new Protocol3(name, m, v, config, scab);
        break;
    default:
        Error("Internal error. Model has bad protocol: <%s>",
            m->GetName().c_str());
        break;
```

devices_text_:

```
std::map<std::string, Generic <LCDText>*> devices_text_;
```

LCDControl::ConfigSetup(),

```
void LCDControl::ConfigSetup() {
    if(!CFG_Get_Root()) return;
    Json::Value::Members keys = CFG_Get_Root()->getMemberNames();

    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = keys.begin(); it != keys.end(); it++ ) {
        if(it->find("display_", 0) != std::string::npos) {
            Json::Value *display = CFG_Fetch_Raw(CFG_Get_Root(), it->c_str());
            Json::Value *driver = CFG_Fetch_Raw(display, "driver");
            if(!driver) {
                Error("CFG: Must specify driver <%s>", it->c_str());
                continue;
            }
            Json::Value *rows = CFG_Fetch_Raw(display, "rows", new Json::Value(-1));
            /*if(!rows->isNumeric() || rows->asInt() == -1) {
                Error("Display <%s> requires number of rows to initialize.", it->c_str());
                delete display;
                delete driver;
                continue;
            }*/
            Json::Value *cols = CFG_Fetch_Raw(display, "cols", new Json::Value(-1));
            /*if(!cols->isNumeric() || rows->asInt() == -1) {
                Error("Display <%s> requires number of columns to initialize.", it->c_str());
                delete display;
                delete driver;
                delete rows;
                continue;
            }*/

            Json::Value *model = CFG_Fetch_Raw(display, "model");
            if(driver->asString() == "crystalfontz") {
                if(model) {
                    devices_text_[*it] = DrvCrystalfontz::Get(*it, this,
                        CFG_Get_Root(), model->asString()); // line 71
                } else {
                    Error("Device <%s> requires a model.", it->c_str());
                    delete display;
                    delete driver;
                    delete rows;
                    delete cols;
                    continue;
                }
            } else if(driver->asString() == "qt") {
                devices_text_[*it] = new DrvQt(*it, this, CFG_Get_Root(),
                    rows->asInt(), cols->asInt());

            } else if(driver->asString() == "pertelian") {
                //devices_text_[*it] = new DrvPertelian(this, CFG_Get_Root(), rows->asInt(), cols->asInt());

            } else
                continue;
            if(model) delete model;
            delete display;
            delete driver;
            delete rows;
            delete cols;
        }

    }

    for(std::map<std::string, Generic<LCDText> *>::iterator it =
        devices_text_.begin(); it != devices_text_.end(); it++) {
        display_keys_.push_back(it->first);
        Error("Starting <%s> %p", it->first.c_str(), it->second);
        Generic<LCDText> *device = it->second;
        device->CFGSetup(it->first);
        device->Connect();
        device->SetupDevice();
        device->BuildLayouts();
        device->StartLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual type of devices_text_ ?

Comment: Also, I assume you can't just iterate through the map, because the map might have things not yet ready to be deleted? (From another LCD, perhaps?)

Comment: GMan: Well, I think that would be modifying the map which in my experience causes problems.

Comment: Can you post `LCD::LCDControl::ConfigSetup()` please?

Comment: @Scott: you are modifying it. `Error("Deleting %s %p", (*it).c_str(), devices_text_[*it]);`, the subscript operator will create the item if it does not exists, your call to `Error` should be within the `if` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that `Protocol1` et al. are subclasses of some `SuperProtocol`?

`devices_text_[*it]` goes through assuming that it contains something of type `SuperProtocol`, so `delete devices_text_[*it]` calls `SuperProtocol::~ SuperProtocol()`.

However, what you really want to call is `Protocol1::~Protocol1()` if you're destructing a `Protocol1`; this only works if you mark `SuperProtocol::~ SuperProtocol()` as `virtual`.

Comment: Bingo that got it! I had two base classes with non-virtual destructors. I didn't know they had to be virtual.

Comment: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7 about when destructors must be virtual.  In short: almost always.  It's one of C++'s (many) pitfalls.

Comment: Indeed, when you say `delete p`, it's going to run the destructor of what `p` points to. If that isn't virtual, then the compiler has no other choice but run the base destructors. By making it virtual, the compiler can find it's way to the correct destructor (which in turn calls the base destructor after running).

Comment: I wouldn't say almost always, just when you plan on deriving from it.

Comment: Ok, GMan, you say "which in turn calls the base destructor." Does that mean the derived constructor should explicitly call the base destructor? Or does it cascade automatically?

Comment: It's automatic. For an object to be constructed, it does: "Base class's constructor, construct all members objects, enter the constructor body." Keep in mind this is recursive, so any base classes will have their bases constructed first, and so on. C++ says that objects are destructed in the reverse order they were constructed. (Try it in a scope, the last variable created is destructed first). So destruction is he reverse of construction: "Enter the destructor body, destruct member objects, run base destructor"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through the keys, finding it in the map, then deleting it, why not just iterate through the map deleting as you go? I'd make a functor and use `for_each` (this isn't a guideline or anything, just my opinion),

```
typedef Generic<LCDText> GenericLCDText;
typedef std::map<std::string, GenericLCDText*> GenericLCDTextMap;
typedef GenericLCDTextMap::value_type GenericLCDTextPair;

struct device_text_deleter : std::unary_function<const GenericLCDTextPair&, void>
{
    void operator()(const GenericLCDTextPair& pPair)
    {
        Error("Deleting %s %p", pPair.first.c_str(), pPair.second);

        delete pPair.second;        
    }
}

std::for_each(devices_text_.begin(), devices_text_.end(), device_text_deleter());
_devices.text_.clear(); // optional, removes the deleted pointers. unnecessary
                        // if this is run in the destructor, since map goes away
                        // shortly after
```

That said, you're code would be improved by the following:

```
// typedef's for readability (would be in header, maybe private)
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;
typedef Generic<LCDText> GenericLCDText;
typedef std::map<std::string, GenericLCDText*> GenericLCDTextMap;

for(StringVector::iterator it = display_keys_.begin();
    it != display_keys_.end(); it++)
{
    // find first! otherwise you're looking up the pair every time
    GenericLCDTextMap::iterator pair = devices_text_.find(*it);

    if (p != devices_text_.end())
    {
        // operator-> is overloaded for iterators but might as well use
        // the pair now.
        Error("Deleting %s %p", pair->first.c_str(), pair->second);

        // no need to check for null, delete null is a-ok
        delete pair->second;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will make it easier to spot the errors. Make sure any base classes you use have virtual destructors.

Check you haven't added a string in the vector twice (this would be "fixed" buy just iterating through the map, though you'll want to find out why duplicates exist in the first place), etc.

I've never tried this before, but maybe add a double delete macro thing (totally untested):

```
#define DOUBLE_DELETE_GAURD static bool x = false; assert(x == false); x = true;
```

Then just add it to your destructor. If you double delete, and the static bool is still around, the assertion will fail. This is completely in undefined la-la land, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that

1. `display_keys_` contains the same string more than once and
2. this string has an associated `Generic <LCDText>*` in `devices_text_`?

In this case the pointer would be given to `delete` twice and this isn't legal...